# Adding a chess tag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tagging

There are quite a lot of questions about [chess](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=chess+is%3Aquestion), some of them are classified as [combinatorial-game-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorial-game-theory), which is (sometimes) incorrect.

Chess it not a mathematical field; however, I can easily imagine people (like myself) that are interested in mathematical questions having chess as a "background" or as a "story" on which the question is being built.

A similar tag - [card-games](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/card-games) - already exists.

Do you agree, such a tag should be added?

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Comment: Sounds bad to me. I have no problem with question that is truely related to chess having a chess tag. But "most" chess problem I see really only use chessboard as a grid to present the problem and has nothing to do with chess.

Comment: I strongly agree with @achille, most problems are not about chess. And while it is debatable whether or not many of the problems about cards relate to card games, we can always assume that there are sufficiently many games under the umbrella of [tag:card-games] to make it so (but I wouldn't go and tag them with [tag:poker] for example). In the case of chess this is rarely the case. If there are more than 30 problems about actual chess, then I'd be willing to give legitimacy to such tag, but I'm not sure that there are.

Comment: Also note the existence of [chess.SE](http://chess.stackexchange.com).

Comment: The voting total for this question - does it represent what people here are thinking about the **question**, or what they think about the **idea**? That is, should I improve the question somehow, or should I just conclude that the community dislikes the idea of having *chess* as a new tag?

Comment: @Asaf Clearly, various people have various thresholds. You say 30 questions, in a [discussion about other tag](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9989/should-there-be-a-simultaneous-equations-tag#comment36671_9989) J.M. says 10 questions.

Comment: @Martin: I used to think ten myself, things have changed since J.M. was around. And my threshold for starting a tag has changed.

Comment: Although chess.SE exists, I'm pretty sure a math problem of moderate depth would be pointed right back here. Most math-based questions are impractical and probably not of much interest there.

Comment: We have [tag:dice] also.

Comment: @MJD: But god doesn't play dice with the universe; no one said anything about an intergalactic game of chess.

Comment: @AsafKaragila https://twitter.com/beranek/status/443489067221544961

Comment: @Andres: I enjoyed the series oh so very much. It should have ended with the uncertainty of Marty and Rust stranded in Carcosa, bleeding badly.

Answer (score 5):

If we are about to introduce [chess](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess) tag, here is a sample of questions which could be considered for such tag. (I am making this post CW, feel free to add other questions. To avoid duplicities, let's order them by id. Also feel free to comment whether or not some questions would be suitable for the suggested tag, so that we can bet clarify its scope.)

- [Is chess Turing-complete?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71760/is-chess-turing-complete)
- [How many different chess-board situations can occur?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169884/how-many-different-chess-board-situations-can-occur)
- [How many turns can a chess game take at maximum?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194008/how-many-turns-can-a-chess-game-take-at-maximum)
- [Does chess have more Nash equilibria than you can find through backwards induction?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254425/does-chess-have-more-nash-equilibria-than-you-can-find-through-backwards-inducti)
- [Some Questions About Chess](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257818/some-questions-about-chess)
- [How can one determine the chess configuration that maximizes the number of possible moves?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346975/how-can-one-determine-the-chess-configuration-that-maximizes-the-number-of-possi)
- [Dominant Strategy in Table Games](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421311/dominant-strategy-in-table-games) (This question asks about other games, too; but a part of this question is: *Does chess have a dominant strategy?*)
- [Is there any hope to solve the game chess?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/613854/is-there-any-hope-to-solve-the-game-chess)
- [A game of Chess - Ideal Solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673147/a-game-of-chess-ideal-solution)
- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/802391/does-chess-have-one-or-more-nash-equilibria
- [The expected outcome of a random game of chess?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845424/the-expected-outcome-of-a-random-game-of-chess)
- [Solving Chess - alternatives to brute force](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850111/solving-chess-alternatives-to-brute-force)
- [Why do people lose in chess?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/859212/why-do-people-lose-in-chess)

Comment: This bunch of questions are really about chess. If there are enough of them, having a tag of them sounds reasonable.

Comment: What about questions about knight's tours?

Comment: @Bach I would consider questions about [knight's tours](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour) more of a combinatorial/graph-theoretical questions, than question about a game of chess.

Comment: Most of these questions fall under game-theory tag

Comment: Martin, what about questions regarding [Knight's Landing](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2366700/intels-most-powerful-chip-ever-packs-emerging-technologies.html)? :)

Comment: New question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/901047/chess-and-mathematics/ (I will only bump the thread after a few of them appear.)

Answer (score -1):

As Go player http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28game%29 i would be against the tag :)

It is much better to use a more specific tag as "game theory" "computability " etc.
then other games can also profit from the gems that are found here.

But I can imagine that chess fans would like it. so maybe not as only tag or so.